# Why is MOSFET continuous drain current much larger than drain-source current on this datasheet?

Tags: mosfet-driver

I am confused by the datasheet for this AOD4184A MOSFET. How can the current through the drain be 50A, but the drain/source current is only 13A? For a continuous load, is not most of the current going through both the drain and source? I thought the Idsm would be larger than the Id because it would include any gate or bulk current. Where is my misunderstanding? And then why do they rate this at 50A when if you were switching a load, it actually can't do more than 10-13A?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are comparing the line for "Continuous Drain Current, Tc=25°C, ID", which is 50A, with the line "Continuous Drain Current, Ta=25°C, IDSM",which is 13A

If so, the suitability is that is the first case, you maintain the case (Tc) at 25°C, while in the second case, you maintain the ambient air (Ta) at 25°C.

So technically, the mosfet can handle the 50A continously, provided you somehow manage to maintain the case at 25°C (good luck for that, I think you will need water cooling at least).

If you just let the Mosfet sit on the PCB with nothing special to dissipate heat, then you are limited to about 13A.

So you get nearly 13A without having to worry much about cooling (provided nothing else nearby dissipates heat). You can have more current for short duration (up to 50A), if the mosfet hasn't time to heat up too much. If you want more than 13A continously, you "just" have to improve cooling (fan, heat-sink on other side of PCB with lots of thermal vias, ...).

Getting the 50A for hours seem extremely difficult (and it would certainly be far easier and cheaper to choose another MOSFET)

PS : for the distinction between ID and IDSM, you can have a look at [this page](http://www.aosmd.com/res/application_notes/mosfets/power_mosfet_basics.pdf) (search for PDSM and IDSM)

Answer (score 4):

Those two ratings are for different thermal conditions. The higher rating is for a **case** temperature of 25C and the lower one is for an **ambient** temperature of 25C.

Comment: Why should one care about the ambient temperature if it's the case temperature that is important for design? It can be relatively cold outside but if my case transistor warms up due to driving heavy loads, why would the ambient temperature be important?

Comment: @ErnestoG The "ambient temperature" is for the part without any external cooling measures.  If you add heat sinks, the case temperature depends on the thermal characteristics of your heat sinks, the dissipated heat energy, and the ambient temperature.  The "ambient temperature" rating tells you what losses the part can take without heat sink, the "case temperature" rating gives you necessary information to calculate your heat sink requirements once you figured out you'll need one.

Comment: Thanks, it pays to read every single character. I completely missed Tc vs. Ta

Answer (score 3):

The 50 amp continuous drain current is a little bit of a smoke-screen. It can't take 50 amps continuously; it can only survive 50 amps if the duration is less than 10 ms. See the [POA curve](http://www.aosmd.com/pdfs/datasheet/AOD4184A.pdf) in the data sheet for confirmation: -

[image]

I expect that the 13 amp figure is a true continuous current value because the power dissipated will be just over a watt and, the device is specified when mounted on a PCB with sufficient copper surface area.